# Android: How to hide my SQLite database in Local Storage?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Development. I want to make an Android app with SQLite database. Now the database should be very highly secured. Encryption is OK But, I want to hide the database from other apps or tools to pull database out.

Comment: _database should be very highly secured..._ So don't store locally...

Comment: SQLite can not be read if devide is not rooted.

Comment: _SQLite can not be read if device not rooted..._ But it can be read if rooted ;) @HoàngĐăng

Comment: if it is rooted there are noting safe, like you said DB should be store server.

Comment: hiding stuff from [drozer](https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/tools/drozer/) isn't a very trivial task either.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the user's database will be in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Other apps do not have access to it, except on rooted devices or other forms of compromised environments. That is the best that you are going to be able to accomplish.